# uploading a file with special charecter filename to s3. minioclient throws get object url error

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, backend, minio

I am writing a backend endpoint in Spring Boot. uploading a file with special cases to the S3 bucket using this end point. but when I try getting the presigned object url for the same uploaded object using Java Minioclient, I get no such key found error. If I go to the official documentation, it says special case files should be handled differently. Anyone have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: I'm confused. You said in the title that it throws an error (which you didn't provide), and then you say that you "get no such key error." Which is it?

Comment: @BlueRobin What I read is: I get `no such key found` error.

Comment: You should provide some important lines of your code, e.g. the Spring endpoint code and the lines of code which move the file to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Without any code or full stack traces, this is extremely difficult to solve